# In JSP Spring Framework, is it possible to create a c:if statement logically based on a user role and another condition?

Tags: java, jsp

For example, I want a field to show up if it's past 12 PM and the user role is teacher.

**EDIT:  I'm asking if there is a way to get the role of the user in JSP. What's the proper way to retrieve that?**

Can I write it like this:

```
<c:if test ="${(Bean.after12PM) and (hasAnyRole('teacher'))}">
//some code
</c:if>
```

Comment: have you tried taht?

Comment: Hi, and I've tried. I know it's not the right syntax.

Comment: You need to be far more specific. User role could mean anything.

Comment: You know the Spring Security JSP Tag to get user roles?  I want to know how I can use that to incorporate it to an if else statement to satisfy another condition.

Comment: For example: 
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMINISTRADOR')">

   </sec:authorize>

Answer (score 0):

Is it the syntax for the jstl if or the value which is passed from a class or a object , not sure what your looking for

```
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
   <p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set property="currentTime" value="${System.CurrentTimeMillis()}"/> 
<c:set property="midnight" value="SET YOUR CUSTOM MIDNIGHT"/>
<c:set property="role" value="SET YOUR CUSTOM ROLE"/> 

<c:if test="${currentTime > midnight && role=="teacher"}">
 .....
</c:if>
```

Should be something like this, check for the correct "and" sintaxe inside that "test" it is been a while I can't recall it exactly.

Remember you can set any of those variables "midnight, role, currentTime" on your controller and set it on session or send it through request